# Change radius to MKCircle on MKMapView with UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, uislider

I'm trying to change the radius of `MKCircle` by moving an `UISlider`.
The problem is that the `radius` property of `MKCircle` is *readonly*.

I tried in this way:

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.radiusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i mt", value];

    MKCircle * oldC = (MKCircle *)self.mapView.overlays[0];

    MKCircle * c = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:self.lastLocation.coordinate radius:value];

    [self.mapView addOverlay:c];

    [self.mapView removeOverlay:oldC];
}
```

but the render is very slow and the circle is rendered tile-by-tile (like a pdf in quartz).
Is there a better and faster way to change the radius ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the answer to this question: [moving/updating MKOverlay on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307316/moving-updating-mkoverlay-on-mkmapview)

basically, instead of removing your old circle and adding a new one, you adjust the current one and tell the mapview to redraw that area.

Comment: MKCircle conforms to the MKOverlay protocol